# Extracting file/page names under the hierarchy of url

Tags: html, css, url, extract

Given I have an link how do I extract file/page names under the hierarchy,

For example in this stackoverflow exchange,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/
There are many links that go after this.

stackoverflow.com/questions/**31236312**
stackoverflow.com/questions/**31235818**
...
Etc

I know "stackoverflow.com/questions/" and wish to find out these numbers, names that go after this.

Is there anyway to do this?

The websites I am looking into uses CSS and 
it does not allow access to, for example, stackoverflow.com/questions/ (I get Error 403--Forbidden)
but only allows specfic pages that goes under it.
These file names consists of mixture of numbers and alphabet character I.e. 72304, or A1103457 etc.

There are over 100 files under that hierarchy and I wish to find out all of its names/url.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can't.There is no way to just grab every page under a given url/domain path.

In longer... You could use a spider like 
https://github.com/mvdbos/php-spider

To follow links and do a breadth depth search, looking for all links it can find under that given url. It will however load every single page it finds, searches it for links and then continues. So it will be very slow on large sites and may result in locking of accounts and breaking terms of service.